# Two trajectories $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ of the six dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Two trajectories $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ of the six dimensional system $\dot{x}=A_{6x6}x$ are given by
$$x_1(t)=t^2e^{-2t}v_1+te^{-2t}v_2+e^{-2t}v_3+v_4 ,\> \> x_2(t)=v_5+e^{-t}v_6 \> \> \> (t\in \mathbb{R})$$
where $v_1,...,v_6$ are constant, nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R^6}$  and $\{v_4,v_5\}$ is a linearly independent set.
$(i)$ Prove that $v_i,i=1,...6$ are generalized eigenvectors of
$A$ and identify the corresponding eigenvalues.
$(ii)$  Prove that $\{v_1,...,v_6\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R^6}$.
$(iii)$ What can you conclude about the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$
of general trajectories of the system $\dot{x}=A_{6x6}x$?

## Solution so far

$x_1(t)=t^2e^{-2t}v_1+te^{-2t}v_2+e^{-2t}v_3+v_4$;
$\dot{x_1}=Ax_1(t)$. Calculate both sides to obtain
$$t^2e^{-2t}(Av_1+2v_1)+te^{-2t}(Av_2+2v_2-2v_1+e^{-2t}(Av_3+2v_3-v_2)+Av_4=0 \> \> \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$
Setting $t=0$,$Av_4=0 \implies v_4\in Null(A)$ is the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 0.
So now we get
$t^2e^{-2t}(A+2)v_1+te^{-2t}((A+2)v_2-2v_1)+e^{-2t}((A+2)v_3-v_2)=0$.
I need help showing that this implies $(A+2)v_1=0$,$((A+2)v_2-2v_1)=0$
$((A+2)v_3-v_2)=0$  I also need help showing that it follows that $v_1$ is an eigenvector corresponding to to eigenvalue -2 and $v_2$ $v_3$ are gegenralized eigenvector for -2.

Comment: Multiply by $e^{2t}$ and take $t=0$. Then continue.

Comment: what about proving basis in part ii @Jonas